# Angular Material mat-table Row Grouping from property

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material-table

I want to display the data in one row with the same ID. But now I have this:

data:

{
"id": "700",
"desc": "Tempo",
"richiesta": "20220087",
"dataElab": "22/09/2022 06:00",
"valore": "13,8"
}, {
"id": "700",
"desc": "Tempo",
"richiesta": "20220088",
"dataElab": "21/09/2022 06:00",
"valore": "12,9"
}, {
"id": "700",
"desc": "Tempo",
"richiesta": "20220089",
"dataElab": "20/09/2022 06:00",
"valore": "12,8"
}

This is the HTML code:

```
  
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8" width="100%">
  
  
  <!-- ID Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    {{element.desc}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let columns of displayedDateColumns" [matColumnDef]="columns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{columns}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    <ng-container *ngIf="element.dataElab == columns">
    {{element.valore}} 
    </ng-container>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  
 
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef= displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

[current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJdDM.png)

How to do this:

[desired view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ6Gq.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need `Array.reduce()` to iterate each element in the array, append key-value pair with `dataElab` as key and `valore` as value to the element and add the element into a new array.

```js
this.data = this.data.reduce((acc: any[], cur: any) => {
  let index = acc.findIndex((x) => x.id == cur.id);
  if (index == -1) {
    cur[cur.dataElab] = cur.valore;
    acc.push(cur);
  } else {
    acc[index][cur.dataElab] = cur.valore;
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Date columns

```
<ng-container
  *ngFor="let columns of displayedDateColumns"
  [matColumnDef]="columns"
>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ columns }}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{ element[columns] }}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1rca8u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)